# javascript appending to a variable from an array

Tags: javascript

i am not sure if its a total n00b question but here goes.

i have a JSON array with values:

```
array[0].1 = "the value I want"
```

now I want to include all "the value I want" into this one variable like:

```
the value I want [1], the value I want [2]....
```

how do i do it?
infact if there is a way I can get the comma seperated values into a variable as it is please let me know.

**EDIT: CLARIFICATION OF QUESTION**

I want to create a variable in which i want to append all the data from the JSON array i have.
for example, if the JSON data reads:

data[0] = value,
data[1] = value,
data[2] = value,
...

i want all the "value" appended into a variable.

Comment: `array[0].1` is invalid syntax.

Comment: why is it invalid. i specifically mentioned its JSON data.

Comment: Because only an identifier can follow the `.` and identifiers cannot start with a number.  the correct syntax would be `array[0][1]`

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. Post the data and the exact output you want if you can't figure out a better way to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var mystring=array.join(", ");` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = 'I,am,a,JavaScript,hacker'
var temp = new Array();
temp = b.split(',');
```

Now the string has been split into 5 strings that are placed in the array temp. The commas themselves are gone.

```
temp[0] = 'I';
temp[1] = 'am';
temp[2] = 'a';
temp[3] = 'JavaScript';
temp[4] = 'hacker.';
```

Taken from [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

**join** is the "opposite" of split - use it to append the elements of an array together into a variable.

```
var j = temp.join(',');  // sets j to 'I,am,a,JavaScript,hacker'
```